# Inserting all csv files into a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, import, csv

I am looking for a way to insert all my csv files into MySQL without having to write several `LOAD DATA INFILE` statements.

I have many csv files I need to insert and the files themselves are very large.

I have tried `*.csv`, but this does not work.

Comment: For situations like this I would use python library [d6tstack](https://github.com/d6t/d6tstack) which makes it easier to deal with multiple files, data schema changes, separators, null values etc. See [d6tstack SQL examples](https://github.com/d6t/d6tstack/blob/master/examples-sql.ipynb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See these previous answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538995/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-into-a-mysql-database

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552042/mysql-loading-multiple-files-into-a-table

Essentially, no.  But it's easy to script this to get a similar result (e.g. one command to import multiple files using a loop).

Answer (score 3):

*<sub>CW answer originally left in the question by its author</sub>*

I wrote a script which worked:

```sh
for f in /var/lib/mysql/[insert name of database here]/*.csv
do
    mysql -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '"$f"' INTO TABLE [nameoftable] 
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES" 
      -u [username] --password= [password] [name of database]
echo "Done: '"$f"' at $(date)"
done
```